# Create a list of scenarios and pass to setup

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new to both scala and Gatling. I just cannot understand the setup method declaration. I have written something like below.

```
val listOfScns = List.tabulate(noOfScns)(n => scenario("Get requests").exec(http("A test request").get("http://someUrl/" + n)))

setUp(
   listOfScns: _*
).protocols(httpConf)
```

This would fail with a compliation error

```
Type mismatch : Expected Seq[PopulatedScenarioBuilder], actual : List[ScenarioBuilder]
```

Which is fair, because the method signature does indeed accept PopulatedScenarioBuilder, by my question is when I am not working, Am I not passing ScenarioBuilder. Is this one of those implicit conversions (which I have not read about fully), Not a clue whats happening here or how to make this work.

Comment: Oops, My bad. Again!!! Realized I need to populate the scenarion builder. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake in coding. Sorry for the confusion